# O(log n) algorithm for sum of 2 elements == given number in BST

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I have seen questions to find sum of 2 elements == k (any given number) in BST. But all solutions are of complexity O(nlgn). Can it be done in lg(n) time?

Comment: Given that you can't even read the whole BST...

Comment: lg(n) is the complexity of finding a single element (or the position of a missing element) in a binary tree. lg(100) is about 6.64. How could you possibly solve this problem of size 100 with 6 or 7 operations?

Comment: Now that I think about it, if the values were in a sorted array instead, you could use indices to the first and last elements, moving them towards each other, last index moves down if sum too high, first index moves up if sum is too low. It's not lgn, but it's better than nlgn.

Comment: @ooga If he had asked it in O(n), it's possible to do your approach in BST also.

Comment: You could do it in O(k * log n)  - check if `1` and `k-1` are in tree. Then check for `2` and `k-2` etc...